# Twitter API application auth only returns forbidden

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to understand how to use oAuth2 with the twitter application only auth so i can display a feed on my web site but i'm stuck at the token acquisition step. I'm probably not doing it right, i can't really get my head around oAuth at all so here's my code, can you guys tell me what i did wrong?

```
//Expired, request a bearer access token
define('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY', 'xyz');
define('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET', 'abc');
$encodedAccessToken = base64_encode(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.':'.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Authorization: Basic '.$encodedAccessToken."\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        'content' => 'grant_type=client_credentials',
        'protocol_version' => 1.1,
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

Then i keep getting a 403 error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in ...

Comment: Note i tried without the content-type header too, and without http 1.1 version

Comment: `stream_context_create` gets an undefined variable `$opts`.

Comment: Marvelous, i look like a total dork now... post the answer so i can credit you ... i feel so bad...

Comment: stop suppressing warnings while developing, error_reporting(-1);.  You are missing a critical warning message about $opts not existing :)

Comment: It's because it's hidden in a darn DIV thats messing up the visuals, i don't turn off notices... I just dug through the output and found the notice i couldn't see...

Comment: @Uberfuzzy And if i did hide the errors while developping, i wouldn't get the warning about the 403 ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as an answer :)

You need to pass `$options`, not the undefined `$opts` to `stream_context_create`.